# Does sin arise in this case?

Tags: dharma, sin

If X goes to Y's house, Y has a low opinion about X and insults him. X is hurt and he thinks that it is his papam. Is there any papam arising to X by inciting or  provoking Y to behave in a bad manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insulting someone is a verbal sin. So, prima facie it is Y who has committed a sin not X.

> Manu Smriti 12.5. Coveting the property of others, thinking in one’s
> heart of what is undesirable, and adherence to false (doctrines), are
> the three kinds of (sinful) mental action
>
> 12.6. Abusing (others, speaking) untruth, detracting from the merits of all men, and talking idly, shall be the four kinds of (evil) verbal
> action.
>
> 12.7. Taking what has not been given, injuring (creatures) without the sanction of the law, and holding criminal intercourse with another
> man’s wife, are declared to be the three kinds of (wicked) bodily
> action.

12.6 above lists the sins that are related to speech or verbal action. Insulting/abusing others falls in that category. So, Y is in fault.

But X's behavior is also not that commendable. Unless he had some emergency why would he visit Y fully knowing that Y dislikes him?

One who dislikes you or have a low opinion of you is not exactly an enemy but someone similar. And it is recommended that one avoids an enemy and not visit his house without strong reasons.

> Manu 4.133. Let him not show particular attention to an enemy, to the
> friend of an enemy, to a wicked man, to a thief, or to the wife of
> another man.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @KappagantulaRamNarayan. If you did like the answer you can accept it by pressing the (✔️) below the voting arrows. It helps the community know that this is the satisfactory answer. Also you might want to contribute an upvote by pressing up arrow